# Why the marker position was incorrect occasionally?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm new to Leaflet map, and I use the OpenStreetMap to show the device location, I confuse why occasionally I got the incorrect marker position for the same latitude and longitude? (it's very far away from the real location).

what did I miss?

my javasript codes below looks correct (I have double check it)

```
renderMap(-6.208763, 106.845599, address, 14);

var marker;
var deviceLocation;
var geoFencing;

function renderMap(lat, lon, address, zoom)
{
    if ($('#device-location').length)
    {
        if (deviceLocation == undefined)
        {
            deviceLocation = L.map('device-location');
        }
        else
        {
            deviceLocation.off();
            deviceLocation.remove();
            deviceLocation = L.map('device-location');
        }

        var latLon = new L.LatLng(lat,lon)
        console.log(latLon);

        deviceLocation.setView(latLon, 14);

        deviceLocation.locate({
            watch: false,
            setView: false,
            timeout: 10000,
            enableHighAccuracy: false
        });

        function onLocationFound(e)
        {
            var radius = e.accuracy;
            //console.log(e.latlng + "  " + radius);

            marker = L.marker(e.latlng)
                .addTo(deviceLocation)
                .bindPopup((geoFenceFound ? 
                    '<strong>Your device</strong> is somewhere around ' + radius + ' meters from this point.</br></br>'
                ))
                .openPopup();

            var circle = L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(deviceLocation);

            var LatLonBounds = circle.getBounds();
            geoFencing = circle;

            if (geoFenceFound)
                deviceLocation.fitBounds(LatLonBounds);
        }

        function onLocationError(e)
        {
            showWarning(e.message);
        }

        function onZoomEnd(e)
        {
            if (marker != undefined)
            {
                console.log('onZoomEnd: ' + marker.getLatLng());
                deviceLocation.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
            }
        }

        function onResize(e)
        {
            if (marker != undefined)
            {
                console.log('onResize: ' + marker.getLatLng());
                deviceLocation.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
            }
        }

        deviceLocation.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
        deviceLocation.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
        deviceLocation.on('zoomend', onZoomEnd);
        deviceLocation.on('resize', onResize);

        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(deviceLocation);

       
    }
}
```

Comment: How far is "very far away", exactly? What's the expected output for your desired input?

Comment: Maybe this is why "enableHighAccuracy" change to true

Comment: it's far it's approx 30Km between the real ones!, as I'm in Indonesia, the marker is actually must be in one city named "Tangerang"  but the map shows it's in "Jakarta", it's already different city!

Comment: [Tangerang](https://geohack.toolforge.org/geohack.php?pagename=Tangerang&params=6_10_41.90_S_106_37_54.80_E_region:ID_type:city(1911914)) is at `-6.178306, 106.631889`, but you provided `-6.208763, 106.845599`. This is a case of a program behaving as you tell it to, not as you want it to. Review your data.